# OP-AMP with varying Vee

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I couldn't understand the purpose of the varying Vee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think this is intended to vary Vee. I think this is simply a way to zero out the OPAMP offset voltage.

Can you give us the source of the picture?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9aFVcVg.png

this is the full circuit, it is an instrumentation amplifier for biomedical purposes.

Comment: Do you have the information which OPAMPs are 1, 2 and 3? It looks like a circut to trim the offset of the circuit.

Comment: well, i took this from a ppt which is from my bio med. teacher. this is not a realization of any circuit. it is just theoritical so these are not real OPAMPs.

Comment: i saw an example from the same ppt. This Vee became Ree(a pot) there. Does that makes any sense ?

Comment: No, sorry, this does not make sense to me. There is not sufficient data to say for sure what the intention was. I'm pretty sure this is for trimming the circuit offset. What is a bio. med. teacher? (Is it what I think it is?)

Comment: sorry english is not my native language its biological and medical engineering teacher lol. thanks for your contribution and for your time.

Comment: @AykutDos  Where does this diagram come from?  Could you post a link to that page?  Perhaps, the discussion in the text can provide the context that we seem to be missing.

Comment: @iggy is right; this is exactly an *offset null adjustment*. Look at the end of this [article](http://www.hamradioindia.com/HRI-THEOR/General/741tutorial.htm)

Comment: turns out that @iggy is right! Thank you for all sir. And Nick Alexeev. Thank you for your time. I will mark this as a true answer.

Answer (score 5):

The label in the diagram refers to the wiper of the potentiometer, which is connected to Vee. The two outer terminals are connected to the offset-null of the Op Amp. The offset null terminals allow you to calibrate an op-amp to ensure the output is exactly zero at exactly equal inputs, despite manufacturing tolerances, by altering the position of the potentiometer. This arrangement where the wiper is connected to Vee and the other two terminals to the offset-null terminals is the most common arrangement of this facility.

Answer (score 3):

As @circuit fantasist said in his now deleted answer

> @iggy is right - this is exactly an *offset null adjustment*.
>   Look at the end of this [article](http://www.hamradioindia.com/HRI-THEOR/General/741tutorial.htm)

The page he cited shows the circuit below. 
(where the term '-Vcc' is synonymous with '-Vee' in the original question).

FWIW - that is an excellent Op Amp introduction page - but much or all of the material has been copied unnattributed from elsewhere, and [**the same material**](http://www.hamradioindia.com/HRI-THEOR/General/741tutorial.htm) appears in dozens of other places on web with no attribution. The original just may be

- "OP AMP BASICS 1.1 CHAPTER 1: OP AMP BASICS James Bryant, Walt Jung, Walt Kester, 
  Greg Kovacs Department of Electrical Engineering Stanford University" and/or "Op Amp Applications Handbook, edited by Walt Jung (Newnes, 2006)", but given the date and use of a 741 the original may be much older.

[image]

Their answer is old and refers to an outdated "741" opamp but the comments are of direct relevance:

- Offset Null Adjustment Procedure for the µA741:Offset null adjustments differ with the application (e.i. Inverting or Non-Inverting Amplifier). Offset-null potentiometers are not placed on design schematics as they would detract from a design. For practice, perform the following Offset Null adjustment if you wish:

  1. Adjust the 10K pot(entio)meter to its center position.
  2. Connect the potmeter outside leads between pins 1 and 5 of the op-amp.Make sure that the power is applied to the design application.
  3. Connect the wiper of the potmeter to the negative supply voltage.
  4. Ensure that input signals are zero or null and that pins 2 and 3 have a dc return to ground.
  5. Measure the output with a dc meter and obtain zero null by adjusting the potentiometer

Answer (score 1):

@Russell McMahon, thanks for the additional clarification. Maybe it would be interesting to see (in the 741 internal structure) how the potentiometer adjusts the offset voltage. A few years ago I revealed the secret of the 741 input stage in the [op-amp Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Operational_amplifier&oldid=436312219#Input_stage) (now it significantly differs). As we can see, the potentiometer changes the transfer ratio (Iout/Iin) of the current mirror Q5,Q6 acting as an active load for the input differential pair Q1-Q4.

[image]

Comment: this is very nice of you to share that. Now my mind is more clear than before. Thank you very much sir!